# Spring jsp checkbox not binding

Tags: java, spring, jsp, checkbox, binding

I know this should be really easy to achieve but I've tried everything and still doesn't work.
My JSP form is quite simple (code not fully posted):

```
<form:form id="form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="AddDoc" commandName="document" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="divManual" class="checkbox">
        <label id="labelManual">
            ${document.manual}
            <form:checkbox id="chkManual" path="manual" label="This is a manual"/>
                <sf:errors path="manual" class="text-danger"/>
        </label>
    </div>
    <input id="submitForm" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="commit" value="Finish">
</form:form>
```

The "document" object is just a simple POJO. When submitting the form the whole object goes through a validation process, then controller retrieves the same object if there are errors and each form parameter is properly binded, except for this "manual" parameter, which should be properly checked/unchecked, but it's always displayed unchecked, no matter if the user checked it before submitting. As you can see in the line `${document.manual}` I print on the same page the parameter's value and I can tell you it is always correct, but for some reason `form:checkbox` doesn't get its value binded.
Please, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Mykong tutorial @ [MyKong Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-checkbox-and-checkboxes-example/) for a complete description of the pre-requisites and know-hows.

Based on comment :
You can always do : ${document.manual} inside a for loop.
Either the  or the java for loop inside the scriptlet.

That wont exactly count as binding though.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've checked that tutorial and cannot make it work... The boolean attribute from model is correctly printed on page, but form:checkbox is always unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Silly me: some js was always setting it unchecked when loading the page. I'm sorry!! Thanks for efford anyway.